# Is there anything wrong with passing a function that returns a component as a prop?

Tags: reactjs

I have multiple very similar tables throughout my application.

Thus, I wanted to design a modular `RootTable` component that can be used to compose other tables.
Assume that I want to generate a table containing a list of persons and a table containing a list of buildings.
Now my problem is that a `<tr>` of the the building table looks very different than a `<tr>` in the person table.

In order to solve this issue, I prepared two components `PersonRow` and `BuildingRow` and designed `RootTable` to be used as follows:

```
<RootTable
  some_prop="some_val"
  ...
  renderRow={(entry) => <BuildingRow some_prop="some_val", ... />
>
```

So, is passing a function that returns a component as a prop bad style for some reason?

Comment: No there is nothing wrong to provide a *creator function* or *render function* as a prop to a component. This is actually an establishd pattern with the name [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html).

Comment: You might want to add a `key` to any row you create because this use case seems to create an array of rows. And keys tell the reconciler if any row changed place, was added, or was deleted. But this is only relevant if your table entries ever get updated after the first render.

Answer (score 0):

**Avoid Inline Function Definition in the Render Function.**

Since functions are objects in JavaScript ({} !== {}), the inline function will always fail the prop diff when React does a diff check. Also, an arrow function will create a new instance of the function on each render if it's used in a JSX property. This might create a lot of work for the garbage collector.

Instead of defining the inline function for props, you can define the arrow function.

```
const renderRow = (entry) => <BuildingRow some_prop="some_val", ... />

<RootTable
  some_prop="some_val"
  ...
  renderRow={renderRow(entry)}
>
```

Comment: That answer has some issues: first: `renderRow={renderRow(entry)}` will call the function instead of assigning it. And second: creating a const arrow function inside the render function is not different from inlining it. To make any difference you would need to create it outside of the render function, so it is *static*. And third: For absolutely most use-cases inlining arrow functions in React is totally fine, and there are only rare cases where `useCallback` would improve performance.